# SQL Work out average from joined column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns I need to display and I need to join on another column that calculates the AVG from the CLUB_FEE column. My code does not work, it throws a "not a single-group group function" Can someone please help? Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID, C.CLUB_FEE, AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) AVGINCOME
FROM SUBSCRIPTION S, CLUB C
WHERE S.CLUB_ID = C.CLUB_ID;
```

Comment: use partition by on avg

Comment: @sanjayradadiya I added "OVER (PARTITION BY S.MEMBER_ID)" after AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) but this only duplicates the data in CLUB_FEE

Comment: why not used group by S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID

Comment: @sanjayradadiya "Not a group by expression"

Comment: @sanjayradadiya - Indeed, why not? (Hint: that suggestion will give a result that has nothing to do with the OP's requirement!)

Answer (score 0):

i Suggest to use Inner join try it also When you include an aggregate function (like avg, sum) in your query, you must group by all columns   :

```
SELECT S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID, C.CLUB_FEE, AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) as AVGINCOME
FROM SUBSCRIPTION S INNER JOIN CLUB C
ON S.CLUB_ID = C.CLUB_ID
GROUP BY
S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID, C.CLUB_FEE ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion however I receive "not a single-group group function"

Comment: i modified my answer look at it i forget the avg need a group by !!

Comment: I tried this but all it does is duplicate the data from CLUB_FEE. I need to calculate the average from the whole CLUB_FEE column and put the result in the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, you need to remove columns from the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.  If you want the average fee paid by any member, then you don't need the `GROUP BY` at all:

```
SELECT AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) as AVGINCOME
FROM SUBSCRIPTION S JOIN
     CLUB C
     ON S.CLUB_ID = C.CLUB_ID;
```

If you want to control the formatting, either use `to_char()`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(C.CLUB_FEE), '999.99') as AVGINCOME
```

(check the documentation for other formats).

Or, cast to a decimal:

```
SELECT CAST(AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as AVGINCOME
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to add "ON" just after "CLUB C" to get it to work. It seems to be correct, but it is displaying the result to 3 decimal places instead of 2. Can you help?

Comment: The rounding function in Oracle is called ROUND - no need to use a different data type (string or decimal). `SELECT ROUND(AVG(...), 2) AS...`

Comment: @mathguy . . . `ROUND()` mathematically rounds the value.  However, the application is still free to render how it wishes.  Applications will render strings as-is, and should follow the definition of numeric/decimal columns.

Comment: Understood, but if this average is needed in further processing, it's probably needed as a number, and if the requirement is for it to be rounded, then it should be rounded as a number, not as a string.

Comment: Also, I noticed that this solution does not answer the problem the OP asked about. Did he/she indicate he/she only needed the average, and not the average as a fourth column in a table with the other three columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to display the three columns and the average, not just the average alone, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID, C.CLUB_FEE, A.AVGINCOME
FROM   SUBSCRIPTION S INNER JOIN CLUB C
                    ON S.CLUB_ID = C.CLUB_ID
                    CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(CLUB_FEE) AS AVGINCOME FROM CLUB) A
;
```

If you need the average rounded to two decimal places, use `ROUND(AVG(CLUB_FEE), 2)` in the subquery.

A fancier solution, which doesn't require a join (so it doesn't scan the `CLUB` table twice), uses AVG as an analytic function - but doesn't partition by anything. You still need the PARTITION BY clause (with an empty column list) to indicate it's used as an analytic function, not as an aggregate.

```
SELECT S.MEMBER_ID, S.CLUB_ID, C.CLUB_FEE,
       ROUND(AVG(C.CLUB_FEE) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)) AS AVGINCOME
FROM   SUBSCRIPTION S INNER JOIN CLUB C
                      ON S.CLUB_ID = C.CLUB_ID
;
```

Even fancier (although functionally identical) - the keyword OVER is needed to indicate analytic function, but you can also write it as `OVER()` (no need to even mention `PARTITION BY NULL`).